# Incorrect rows estimate for joins

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I have simple query (Postgres 9.4):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    bo_labels L
    LEFT JOIN bo_party party ON (party.id = L.bo_party_fkey)
    LEFT JOIN bo_document_base D ON (D.id = L.bo_doc_base_fkey)
    LEFT JOIN bo_contract_hardwood_deal C ON (C.bo_document_fkey = D.id)
WHERE
    party.inn = '?'
```

Explain looks like:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                           
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 Aggregate  (cost=2385.30..2385.30 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=31762.367..31762.367 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                                                  
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.28..2385.30 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=7.621..31760.776 rows=1694 loops=1)                                                                                    
         Join Filter: ((c.bo_document_fkey)::text = (d.id)::text)                                                                                                                                     
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 101658634                                                                                                                                                       
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.28..106.33 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.110..54.635 rows=1694 loops=1)                                                                                 
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..105.69 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=0.081..4.404 rows=1694 loops=1)                                                                                       
                     ->  Index Scan using bo_party_inn_idx on bo_party party  (cost=0.43..12.43 rows=3 width=10) (actual time=0.031..0.037 rows=3 loops=1)                                            
                           Index Cond: (inn = '2534005760'::text)                                                                                                                                     
                     ->  Index Only Scan using bo_labels__party_fkey__docbase_fkey__tnved_fkey__idx on bo_labels l  (cost=0.42..29.80 rows=1289 width=17) (actual time=0.013..1.041 rows=565 loops=3) 
                           Index Cond: (bo_party_fkey = (party.id)::text)                                                                                                                             
                           Heap Fetches: 0                                                                                                                                                            
               ->  Index Only Scan using bo_document_pkey on bo_document_base d  (cost=0.43..0.64 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.022..0.025 rows=1 loops=1694)                                       
                     Index Cond: (id = (l.bo_doc_base_fkey)::text)                                                                                                                                    
                     Heap Fetches: 1134                                                                                                                                                               
         ->  Seq Scan on bo_contract_hardwood_deal c  (cost=0.00..2069.77 rows=59770 width=9) (actual time=0.003..11.829 rows=60012 loops=1694)                                                       
 Planning time: 13.484 ms                                                                                                                                                                             
 Execution time: 31762.885 ms
```

http://explain.depesz.com/s/V2wn

What is very annoying is incorrect estimate of rows:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..105.69 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=0.081..4.404 rows=1694 loops=1)
```

Because that postgres choose nested loops and query run about 30 seconds.
With `SET LOCAL enable_nestloop = OFF;` it accomplished just in a second.

What is also interesting, I have `default_statistics_target` = 10000 (at max value) and on all 4 tables run `VACUUM VERBOSE ANALYZE` just before.

As postgres [does not gather statistic between tables](http://www.cybertec.at/2014/07/detecting-wrong-planner-estimates/#comment-1497932525) such case is [very likely possible to happens](https://tech.zalando.com/blog/analyzing-extreme-distributions-in-postgresql/) for other joins too.

Without external extension [pghintplan](https://en.osdn.jp/projects/pghintplan/) it is not possible change `enable_nestloop` for just that query.

Is there some other way I could try to force use more speedy way to accomplish that query?

### Update by comments

I can't eliminate join in common way. My main search is there any possibilities change statistic (for example) to include desired values which break normal statistical appearance? May be other way to force postgres to change weight of `nested loops` to use it not so frequently?

Could also someone explain or point to documentation how postgres analyzer for nested loops of two results with 3 (exact correct) and 1289 (which will really 565, but actually such error different question) rows made assumption what in result will be only 1 row??? I've speak about that part of plan:

```
           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..105.69 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=0.081..4.404 rows=1694 loops=1)                                                                                       
                 ->  Index Scan using bo_party_inn_idx on bo_party party  (cost=0.43..12.43 rows=3 width=10) (actual time=0.031..0.037 rows=3 loops=1)                                            
                       Index Cond: (inn = '2534005760'::text)                                                                                                                                     
                 ->  Index Only Scan using bo_labels__party_fkey__docbase_fkey__tnved_fkey__idx on bo_labels l  (cost=0.42..29.80 rows=1289 width=17) (actual time=0.013..1.041 rows=565 loops=3) 
                       Index Cond: (bo_party_fkey = (party.id)::text)
```

On first glance it looks initially wrong. What statistics used there and how?
Does postgres maintain also some statistics for indexes?

Comment: the `LEFT JOIN bo_party party` could be `JOIN bo_party party` (the `WHERE  party.inn = '?'` already makes it degrade into a plain join.)

Comment: Sure. But it does nothing for statatistic understanding.

Comment: Without DDL (and some descriptives, and some configuation parameters) it is not possible to answer detailed performance questions. it *appears* there is now index available for `ON (party.id = L.bo_party_fkey)` (looks like a FK reference to me, could be served by a composite index) Again: DDL.

Comment: Note: there is a *statistical* difference between an ordinary JOIN on any column(s), and a JOIN via a FK reference.

Comment: @joop could you please be more verbose? What it mean under "statistical difference between an ordinary JOIN on any column(s), and a JOIN via a FK reference"?

Comment: Well: for a FK, you can be sure that any non-NULL value is present in the referenced table (but not all values in the referenced table have to be adressed). For unrelated tables, the only information the planner has are the statistics (if present); and any amount of rows could match.Adding an index does not change this association. (it does cause statistics to be maintained, which can help the planner when deciding whether to use the index) And *please* add the table definitions, including PK/FK and secundary indexes.

Comment: @joop, table definitions: http://paste.fedoraproject.org/291749/14478394/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't have a good sample data to test my answer but I think it might help.

Based on your join columns I'm assuming the following relationship cardinality:

```
1) bo_party (id 1:N bo_party_fkey) bo_labels 
2) bo_labels (bo_doc_base_fkey N:1 id) bo_document_base 
3) bo_document_base (id 1:N bo_document_fkey) bo_contract_hardwood_deal
```

You want to count how much rows were selected. So, based on the cardinality in **1)** and **2)** the table "bo_labels" have a many to many relationship. This means that joining it with "bo_party" and "bo_document_base" will produce no more rows than the ones existing in the table.

But, after joining "bo_document_base", another join is done to "bo_contract_hardwood_deal" which cardinality described in **3)** is one to many, perhaps generating more rows in the final result.

This way, to find the right count of rows you can simplify the join structure to "bo_labels" and "bo_contract_hardwood_deal" through:

```
4) bo_labels (bo_doc_base_fkey 1:N bo_document_fkey) bo_contract_hardwood_deal
```

A sample query could be one of the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM bo_labels L 
LEFT JOIN bo_contract_hardwood_deal C ON (C.bo_document_fkey =     L.bo_doc_base_fkey)
WHERE 1=1
  and exists
  (
    select 1
    from bo_party party 
    where 1=1
      and party.id = L.bo_party_fkey
      and party.inn = '?'
  )
;
```

or

```
SELECT sum((select COUNT(*) from bo_contract_hardwood_deal C where C.bo_document_fkey = L.bo_doc_base_fkey)) 
FROM bo_labels L 
WHERE 1=1
  and exists
  (
    select 1
    from bo_party party 
    where 1=1
      and party.id = L.bo_party_fkey
      and party.inn = '?'
  )
;
```

I could not test with large tables, so I don't know exactly if it will improve performance against your original query, but I think it might help.

Comment: Unfortunately count is just example. Really there selected several columns from all tables (and really there may be some other WHERE conditions by them, it just simplified for now). So, I need that join.

Comment: @Hubbitus I think the original query would help to find an optimized query, as long as postgres does not support hints by default

Comment: I can't eliminate join in common way. My main search is there any possibilities change statistic (for example) to include desired values which break normal statistical appearance? May be other way to force postgres to change weight of nested_loops to use it not so frequently?